# Scanf function between c++ and assembler

Tags: c++, assembly, inline

I have this code:

```
void scan ()
{
    char scanf_fmt[] = "%c";
    char printf_fmt[] = "%c\n";
    char character[30];

    _asm
    {
        push 1 // Buffer size, you can also write `push size character`

        lea eax, character
            push eax     // Pointer to character

            lea eax, scanf_fmt
            push eax                // Pointer to format string
            call scanf_s


            add esp, 12             // Clean up three pushes

            movzx eax, byte ptr[character] // MOVZX: Load one unsigned byte into a 32-bit-register
            push eax// Character as value


            lea eax, printf_fmt
            push eax // Pointer to format string

            call printf 

            add esp, 8               // Clean up two pushes era 8
    }

    //return 0;
}
```

This function prints the first character in a word, but I copied this function and I changed the name, for example: `scan()` to `scan2();`.

When I use the new function, the program takes the previously word of the function `scan`.

How I can do to read me a different word?

Comment: `%c` only consumes a single character, and leaves the rest in the buffer. You will have to read those out or discard them.

Comment: Thanks, so Can I make the flush with xor eax, eax? or How Can I make the flush?

Answer (score 0):

using

```
lea eax, character
push eax     // Pointer to character
```

you tell scanf where to put the data scanned, in your case into

```
char character[30];
```

if you have a 2nd function, but use the same buffer, you'll override each others input

if you want to save the content, create a 2nd buffer, e.g.

```
char character[30];
char character2[30];
```

and use this instead:

```
        push 1 
        lea eax, character2
        push eax                // Pointer to buffer
        lea eax, scanf_fmt
        push eax                // Pointer to format string
        call scanf_s
        add esp, 12             // Clean up three pushes

        movzx eax, byte ptr[character2] 
        push eax                // Character as value
        lea eax, printf_fmt
        push eax                // Pointer to format string
        call printf 
        add esp, 8               // Clean up two pushes era 8
```